# faq content on every page , duplicate content or not ?

Tags: seo

hey guys i have a client who needs a FAQ modal popup on every page , which means the FAQ should be accessible from every page .

so basically the html content of the FAQ section appears on every page , is this content duplication ? will google penalize me for this ? i site is already build , so i am just optimizing it . as of now its such that every page has the faq content .

[image]

as of now i have something like the above appearing on every page (i have about 20 pages) with alot of important content in it .

can somebody tell me if this is going to be classified as duplicate content . ?

i saw the following threads :

[duplicate content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52792/duplicate-content-on-a-site)

[duplicate html content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52965/duplicate-content-on-the-same-page-seo-ramifications)

but my situation is slightly different .

Comment: You should check out the tag `aside`

Comment: @Martijn i know that tag , but , how do you suggest i use it ?

Comment: "The <aside> tag defines some content aside from the content it is placed in. The aside content should be related to the surrounding content." Source: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_aside.asp

Answer (score 2):

It *may* "distract" Google when it analyzes your webpages, trying to give them a primary subject. So even if you do some kind of optimization, it may cause some kind of trouble. In a similar situation I've seen footer content on a text widget that appeared in the snippet description of some pages.

But it all depends on what's actually your page, so we cannot say anything for sure.

Here you have some words about from Matt Cutts on a similar situation https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=26&v=Vi-wkEeOKxM where it says explicitly that Google doesn't penalizes webpages for duplicate content if it's legit content.

Anyway: if you need to show that kind of content, just "call" it from a static source, don't copy and paste through all your pages. The web is conceived for linking content.

Use Javascript or iframes.

Comment: Please don't use iframes for this, it's 2015.